# Is there an Ubuntu Touch function similar to toasts in Android?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, android, ubuntu-sdk

I'm jumping into development for the Ubuntu phone and I've found a situation where I believe a short, ephemeral message similar to [Android's toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) would be appropriate.  Is there a similar function built into the Ubuntu SDK, or should I look at other methods of user interaction?